# How can I get a notification when a chart is removed from a hawtio dashboard

Tags: hawtio

I need to know when one of my charts have been deleted from a hawtio dashboard. Is that possible?

I have a plugin that adds charts to a hawtio dashboard. Once added, the charts can be customized. However, since I can't change the charts' search params once they have been added, I'm adding them with a short chart id. That id is then used to lookup the full options from localStorage when rendering the chart.

This all works fine. However, when a chart is deleted from the dashboard, I'd like to clean up my localStorage.

For now I'm running a customized build of hawtio.war. I've added a

```
scope.$broadcast("removedFromDashboard");
```

to gridsterDirective.ts just before the scope gets destroyed in the removeWidget() function. I then listen for that event and clean up my localStorage. This works but I don't want to distribute my custom hawtio.war file with my plugin.

Is there an existing way to know when my dashboard chart is removed? I've looked in the event.targetScope that gets passed in my $scope.on('$destroy') event, but it appears identical to a normal destroy that I get when I navigate off of the dashboard page.

Comment: I am not aware, try to ask stan lewis (gaschrumb) on the hawtio IRC chat room

Comment: Yeah, to be honest it might be best to just submit a PR with your change, currently the dashboard doesn't support this but I think it'd be a really good enhancement.